# Catch WCF Timeout

Tags: wcf, connection-timeout, timeoutexception

Currently i have an issue regarding the WCF Timeout. The problem is how catch the error from WCF and catch it in global.asax ? I put try and catch in the business service, however it does not work. 
Appreciate much for your answer.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first determine what causes the time out exception - then handle the exception properly.

If your service breaks (though I doubt a timeout falls under this category) you can catch it using the following in global.asax:

```
serviceHost.Faulted += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Faulted);
```

Note this isn't a good solution. Find the exact problem then use mocking frameworks (such as Moq) to simulate how your code (both client and service) will behave/recover in case your service takes too long to respond.